# Как добавить кнопку запуска видео выше плеера

Tags: jquery, css, видео

Имеется видео на компьютере нужно добавить постер выше плеера, так же отдельно есть чёрный экран и кнопка. При нажатии на оранжевую кнопку запуск видео. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sBbP.jpg - Ссылка на постер

```
 <div class="box">
        <video width="360" height="200" controls="controls" poster="images/play_video.jpg">
            <source src="int_board.mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
```

Вот, что в итоге получается https://i.stack.imgur.com/USyLy.jpg

**P.S. на скрине видны слева и справа чёрная тень, как её убрать?**

Comment: Чтобы вставить выше плеера картинку - просто вставьте её <img src=""> до дива с плеером или в див с плеером но выше видео....
И вобще не понятно что конкретно нужно и что у вас не получается?

Comment: https://imgur.com/t1MDBOB - я вставил постер но он ниже кнопок контроля и как бы идёт перекрытие, я бы хотел убрать эту белую кнопку и заменить оранжевой с чёрный задним фоном и по клику запускать видео. Так же на скрине видно справа и слева непонятная тень, как её убрать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так)

```js
  $(".button_play").on("click", function(){
  $('#video')[0].play();
  $('.button_play').hide();
  });
  $("#video").on("click", function(){
  $('#video')[0].pause();
  $('.button_play').show();
  });
```

```css
.button_play {
background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sBbP.jpg') no-repeat center center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
cursor: pointer;
position:absolute;
top:0;
z-index: 10;
left:0;
}
.video_block {
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
position:relative;
float:left;
}
#video {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #000;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video_block">
  <div class="button_play"></div>
  <video id="video" height="auto" controls="controls" preload="none">
 <source type="video/mp4" src="https://mobclip.net/uploads/files/2018-11/1541658097_ariana-grande-breathin.mp4">
</video>
</div>
```